# ¿Cómo implementar ReactiveUI ObservedChange?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, programación-reactiva

Quiero usar el `EventHandler` MouseEnter & MouseLeave para cambiar el `OpasityMask` de las imágenes. Algunas imágenes se generarán en tiempo de ejecución y en diferentes páginas. El punto es que necesito tener acceso al **`sender`** para cambiar la propiedad `OpacityMask` en el comando MouseHover en la **clase ViewModel**.

### **View**

```
this.WendActivated(d =>
{
    d(this.BindCommand(ViewModel, 
       vm => vm.MouseHover, 
       v => v.myImage, 
       myImage.Events().MouseEnter));
});
```

---

### **ViewModel**

```
private void Image_MouseEnterExecute(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    PlaySound("mouse_hover.mp3");

    var image = sender as Image;
    image.OpacityMask = new SolidColorBrush { Opacity = 1, Color = Colors.Black };
}
```

No sé cómo implementar `ObservedChange` para cambiar el `OpacityMask`.

```
public ReactiveCommand MouseHover => image_MouseEnter;
public ObservedChange<object, object> ImageBrush => imageBrush;

public ViewModel()
{
    //Can not convert method group to action.
    image_MouseEnter = ReactiveCommand.Create(Image_MouseEnterExecute);
    //Can not convert method group to action.
    imageBrush = ReactiveCommand.Create(Image_MouseEnterExecute);
}
```

¿Por qué no pongo un **Binding** a la propiedad `OpacityMask`? El problema es que tengo muchas imágenes, algunas creadas en tiempo de ejecución. No quiero que todas las Imágenes cambien al mismo tiempo, o que crear una propiedad `OpacityMask` en la **clase ViewModel** para cada Imagen.

---

Espero que alguien con experiencia me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Prueba con esto: d(this.BindCommand(ViewModel, 
       vm => vm.MouseHover, 
       v => v.myImage, nameof(myImage.MouseEnter));

Comment: me he dado cuenta que no soporta parametros desde el view.

Comment: Porqué mezclas cosas de la parte UI en el ViewModel? edit: estás aplicando mal el concepto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deja ver si esto te ayuda...

Primero, cambia tu ViewModel, trata de no utilizar ninguna referencia de la vista en el VM.

Lo que intentas hacer es resposabilidad de la vista pues son cosas que afectan a la UI.

En tu vista puedes hacer:

```
myImage.Events().MouseEnter
    .Do(_ => PlaySound("mouse_hover.mp3"))
    .Select(e => myImage)
    .Subscribe(image => image.OpacityMask = new SolidColorBrush { Opacity = 1, Color = Colors.Black });
```

Recuerda que MVVM (y ReactiveUI) se tratan de separar responsabilidades, el ViewModel define la logica de negocios y de presentación, no detalles de la vista como manejo de controles.

EDIT: A ver si te sirve este código:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Color" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

No tengo VS a la mano, espero te funcione.

Comment: mi objetivo era agrupar el codigo del mouse en una clase, pero me he dado cuenta de que Reactive UI tiene algunas limitaciones.

Comment: ¿A que limitaciones te refieres? yo hasta ahora no he visto ninguna.

Comment: Lo que yo menciono de no mezclar UI con ViewModel no es limitación, es así como funciona MVVM, la idea de MVC, MVVM, MVP, y los patrones de diseño es ese, separar responsabilidades.

Comment: La limitacion es que no puedo enviar el `sender` como parametro para un comando.

Comment: con la respuesta que me diste tengo que escrivir ese codigo en cada view, el objetivo era que desde el xaml el viewmodel gestionara el evento del mouse.

Comment: ademas si tengo 100 imagenes tengo que hacer lo mismo por cada imagen.

Comment: No entiendo, igual tendrías que escribir el código que enlaza el comando con el evento mouseenter en cada vista. Si a lo que te refieres es que quieres que un conjunto de imagenes se manejen con el mismo evento, puedes concatenar el *.Events().MouseEnter

Comment: en el xaml quiero `<Image MouseEnter="Binding MyEvento">` pero que el evento este en un ViewModel compartido para todos los views.

Comment: De poder, se puede, pero entonces para qué usar MVVM? La idea de MVVM, como comenté, es separar respinsabilidades y que no termines con código espagueti. ¿porqué mejor no usas un trigger en XAML? lo puedes aplicar automáticamente a los controles de tipo Image. Si solo ocupas ese comportamiento en una ventana lo agregas al diccionario de la ventana.

Comment: Si pones un ejemplo en tu respuesta de como hacerlo con un trigger, la marco como mejor respuesta.